# Allow an Image in a cell in a gridView to overflow behind other cells

Tags: android, layout, gridview

i have a GridView with books images, 4 books on each row, I am trying to have an image of a shelf behind each row.
the image of course need to be attached to the GridView and scroll with it.
One Idea I had was to have an Image of a shelf on the first item of each row, and somehow have that image stretch behind the other 3 cells?

couldn't find how to have the image not crop with the cell.
Is it possible
Can anyone suggest a different solution to the problem ?

Thank you